# Computed properties are not re-calculating when dependent oneWay CP updates

Tags: ember.js

Lets say I have a `oneWay` CP which is initially bound to a model property (and is hence free to diverge if updated)

The CP can be set to values `fixed` & `dynamic`. I have some `equal` CPs which in turn rely on this `oneWayCp` changing

```
oneWayCp: oneWay('model.field')
isFixed: equal('oneWayCp', 'fixed').volatile().readOnly(),
isDynamic: equal('oneWayCp', 'dynamic').volatile().readOnly(),
```

I'm seeing a weird bug wherein `isFixed` & `isDynamic` don't update when `oneWayCp` is updated

Is this expected behavior ?

Comment: Did a reproduction of what I see on Ember Twidde
https://ember-twiddle.com/1934386ad97e960cac37b36cf0068847?openFiles=controllers.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route

Go to the route `/my-route`
The clicking of radio buttons should have updated the values `isFixed` and `isDynamic`, but its not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your problem is `.volatile()`. Basically this disables the *update on dependency keys* behaviour.

[Here](https://ember-twiddle.com/1934386ad97e960cac37b36cf0068847?openFiles=controllers.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route) is a fixed twiddle.

So you should do this:

```
oneWayCp: oneWay('model.field')
isFixed: equal('oneWayCp', 'fixed').readOnly(),
isDynamic: equal('oneWayCp', 'dynamic').readOnly(),
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.3/classes/ComputedProperty/methods/volatile?anchor=volatile):

> It also does not automatically fire any change events. You must manually notify any changes if you want to observe this property.